# Making multiple Axios get requests with an array of links?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, axios

I have a function that I want to return all of the upcoming assignments for a student. I start by running another async function that returns me all of the course ID's the student is in for a term and year. I then fill an array with .get urls for each class.

My issue is with understanding and using `Axios.all()` as I want to perform multiple calls to each class, and then to sort through each assignment and only save the assignments that are due later than the students current date. The issue I am facing is that `axios.all([urls])` returns `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 401`. I cant figure out why I cannot return the proper data from each url call. I narrowed it down to it being an issue with how I am setting up my axios.all call. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
//Get all upcoming assignments from each class for a user
async function getAssignments(){
    //Make multiple requests to api
    axios
        .all([urls])
        //Loop through each assignment for each class
        .then(
            axios.spread((...res) =>{
                for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
                    //If the due date of the assignment is due later than the users current date, push to array
                    if (res.data[i]['due_at'] > date.toISOString()) {
                        assignments.push(res.data[i])
                    }
                }
                //Output all assignments
                return assignments
            })
        )
}
```

**Update:**
I forgot to pass a token to my header and after a bit more tweaking it will now grab a specified url from my array. But I need it to now grab every url in the array and make the calls concurrently. Though I am a bit stumped, would I just need to make a for loop for the `.get` or something more specific? Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
//urls is the array filled with links. Need for the axios calls to happen concurrently
axios.all([axios.get(
    urls[0],
    {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    }
)])
//Loop through each assignment in a specfied class in canvas
.then(
    axios.spread((...res) =>{
        for (var i = 0; i < res[0].data.length; i++) {
            //If the due date of the assignment is due later than the users current date, push to array
            if (res[0].data[i]['due_at'] > date.toISOString()) {
                assignments.push(res[0].data[i])
            }
        }
        console.log(assignments)
    })
)
.catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Comment: The code looks correct and it should work, what is the issue you are facing. You need to be more specific

Comment: @Sohan the issue I am facing is that axios.all([urls]) returns  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 401`. I cant figure out why I cannot return the proper data from each url call. I narrowed it down to it being an issue with how I am setting up my `axios.all` call.

Comment: It is `401`. Looks like the remote endpoint is secured and you are not passing valid token in `Authorization` header? Please verify that first? Also update you question with error you are getting. It gives more context

Comment: @Sohan That is something I forgot to add to the call. Thank you for noticing that! I just need to now have it for `axios.all` to get every link in the array. I will update my post accordingly with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the header when at first at axios instance level assuming you have created your axios instance you can simply,

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer AUTH_TOKEN';

//Get the course ID for each class the user is assigned to
    const courseID = await getCurrentCourses('Spring', '2021')
    //Fill the array with urls to each course assignment page
    for(let i = 0; i < courseID.length; i++){
        urls.push(axios.get('https://example.com/api/v1/courses/' + allCourseID[i] + '/assignments'));
    }
     //Make multiple requests to api
        axios.all(urls)
            //Loop through each assignment for each class
            .then({......});
```

Comment: Thanks! I have my header now properly set up, but I am still running into the issue where `axios.all` wont run every url in my array. It returns the error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array`. I can't figure out how to iterate through my `urls[]` array to have the `axios.all` to run

Comment: You already have `url []`. Why are you passing `[urls]`. Check my updated answer

Comment: @OrangeCry if this worked for you, could you also upvote this answer